# How to get around a 'by design' issue with Windows dir?

Tags: windows, dos, long-filenames

dir /b produces a nice file-only list

dir /x produces a detailed listing (date, time, size, longname, shortname)

However, if you combine the two (i. e. dir /b /x) the /x switch gets ignored. this behavior as per [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240666) page is by design.

So if you ask for a simple list containing only of shortnames of files, Redmond (Microsoft) says it is against the rules of heaven to give it to you.

How could one get around this 'by design' issue?

many thanks in advance

p.s. this is to help me achieve something explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684535/batch-rename-issue-when-dealing-with-special-chracters-in-the-filename) question. five kind friends have posted answers to whom i am very grateful, but non of the answers helped me get what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %X in (`dir /b`) do @echo %~nsxX
```

Or, if you want fully-qualified path names:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %X in (`dir /b`) do @echo %~fsX
```

For more information, see the `for` help:

```
for /?
```

Note that if you use these commands in a batch file, you'll need to double up the `%` signs. For example:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%X in (`dir /b`) do @echo %%~nsxX
```

Comment: both commands fail on seeing a parenthesis. if you have milad(1).mp3, and milad(2).mp3, the command produces two items bith as milad and discard anything following it (even the dot and extension: .mp3). whereas dir /x produces MILAD(~1.MP3 and MILAD(~2.MP3

Comment: The problem was caused by long filenames with spaces in them. I've updated my answer with corrections to the commands to fix this.

Comment: Good idea. But it needs a little change. The first one missing extensions, so add extensions and hide the echo command:
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %I in (`dir /b`) do @echo %~nxsI

Comment: Good catch on the dropped extensions. The echo was really just for demonstration purposes, but it is nicer if it's hidden. I've updated the original post with both of these changes.

Comment: could you have a look at my other question too? i think i've done it in a very naive way - to be exact, i've patched code by others with a few lines by myself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Short of dumping dir /x to a text file and parsing it, I'm not sure what to suggest.  Do you have the ability to run whatever it is you're doing in code?

It's a more complicated solution, but writing something using perl or another scripting language; or go whole hog and write some code in C#.

I suspect that you're going to get much the same kind of answers that you got on the previous question...

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own directory listing executable.  It wouldn't take much to whip up something in C#.  Use Directory.GetFiles() to retrieve the directory listing, and pass each one into the "GetShortPathName()" Win32 function.

This page has a decent example of how to call GetShortPathName() from C#:
http://csharparticles.blogspot.com/2005/07/long-and-short-file-name-conversion-in.html